# How to warp text in container around centered image / div

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a `<div>` located in the middle of its parent element, and have the text flow around it (similar to "wrap text" mode in Microsoft Word).

The following image shows what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

The image is placed somewhere in the middle of a paragraph and the text flows around it.

How can this be achieved with HTML/CSS?

Would any of the CSS properties `display:flex`, `display:grid` or `clip-path: circle()`,`shape-outside: circle()` solve this?

To formulate the question another way. It is possible to reposition an element in a way that affects the layout boxing (beside using `margin`)?

Because using `position:relative` just moves the visual rendering and doesn't affect the layout of another element and its content.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Clearly English is not your first language :) What is `text`? That's not a valid HTML tag, so it's anyone's guess what that is. I think you should draw some pictures and upload them showing what you're trying to achieve and then show some actual code, to show what you've tried. Maybe even on codepen.io

Comment: sure you right, i'm hebrew speaker :) . text is real `Text Node` not some element

Comment: Please show your html and your CSS. I can't imagine what a `Text Node` is.

Comment: I updated the question with image like you suggest

Comment: Ok but now you need to describe what exactly you are trying to do. Are you simply trying to place the image over the middle of a container? Are you trying to get the text to flow around the image? Are you actually aiming for the middle of a div (even if it's width and height changes) or are you just trying to apply top and bottom margins. It's not really clear what your goal is here.

Comment: This bit makes no sense at all: "it is possible to position/move element beside margin that effect the layout boxing ? using position:relative just move the visual rendering not the layout rect box."

Comment: I'll ask for a third (and final) time :) Please show your HTML and CSS. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: I edited the question and hopefully make it more clear. The question is not directed to a particular structure of HTML and CSS. Any combination of CSS and HTML is welcomed

Answer (score -1):

Hey I think what you need is shape-outside: circle();
This will make the text go around your shape.

Comment: close: `shape-outside: inset` would be more applicable. see: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/